# Hexo: How to Query DB in a plugin?

Tags: javascript, static-site, hexo

I'm trying to create a plugin for Hexo and it's in the scripts folder. I'm trying to write tests for it as a develop it with `jasmine-node`. How do I make db queries in my spec file? For instance, I don't have the `site` variable available and writing `require('site')` doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `_config.yml` variable URL?

If so, inside plugin you may access by `this.config.url`.